# Missing Google app id

Tags: android

Trying to sync my android project in android studio but it failed with an error

```
Missing Google App Id. Please follow instructions on https://firebase.google.com/ to get a valid config file that contains a Google App Id
```

Even my application contained `google-services.json` inside app directory.
How to solve this problem?